# how to feed a function's parameters with arguments using another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that converts time expressed in minutes into a readable format (days, hours, minutes). I'm trying to feed into part of that function's parameters - arguments that could be in many languages via another function but it doesn't work.

I've tried to create a global var french = ["jours", "heures", "minutes"]; didn't work either.

I'm sorry if the question is stupid. I'm quite the noob in JS and i'm trying to work only in JS for now so please don't give any solutions using jQuery i'm trying to get pure JS logic here... Thanks in advance!!

```
function translate(language){
  switch(language) {
  case french:
    ["jours", "heures", "minutes"]
    break;
  case german:
    ["Tage", "Stunden", "Minuten"]
    break;
  default:
    ["days", "hours", "minutes"]
}
};

function displayResult() {// Displays the result of the calculation

  let ascentResult = ascent();
  let flatResult = flat();
  let combinedResult = (ascent() + flat());
    if (ascentResult !== 0 && flatResult === 0) {
    document.getElementById("displayResult").innerHTML = ("Total climbing time is " + convertMinutesToHours(ascentResult, translate(french)));
    document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = " ";
  } else if (ascentResult === 0 && flatResult !== 0) {
    document.getElementById("displayResult").innerHTML = ("Total normal walking time is " + convertMinutesToHours(flatResult, translate(french)));
    document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = " ";
  } else if (ascentResult === 0 && flatResult === 0) {
    document.getElementById("displayResult").innerHTML = ("You didn't provide any data");
    document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = " ";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("displayResult").innerHTML = ("Total walking time is " + convertMinutesToHours(combinedResult , translate(french)));
    document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = ("Out of which " + convertMinutesToHours(flatResult, translate(french)) + " of normal walking and " + convertMinutesToHours(ascentResult, translate(french)) + " of climbing");
  };
};


function convertMinutesToHours(result, days, hours, minutes) { 
  if (result >= 60 && result <= 1440) { // from 1 hour to 24 hours
    let totalHours = Math.floor(result / 60);
    let totalMinutes = (result.toFixed(2) - Math.floor(result)) * 60;
    return (totalHours + " " +hours+ " and " + totalMinutes.toFixed(0) + " "+minutes);
  } else if (result > 1440){ // for more than 24 hours - add "days"
    let totalDays = Math.floor(result / 1440); 
    let totalMinutesAfterDays = (result.toFixed(9) - Math.floor(result)) * 1440; 
    let totalHoursAfterDays = Math.floor(totalMinutesAfterDays / 60);
    let totalMinutesAfterHours = (totalMinutesAfterDays.toFixed(2) - Math.floor(totalMinutesAfterDays)) * 60;
    return (totalDays + " " +days+ " " + totalHoursAfterDays + " " +hours+ " and " + totalMinutesAfterHours.toFixed(0) + " " +minutes);
  } else {
    return (Math.floor(result) + " "+minutes);
  };
};


document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", displayResult());
```

I expected the function convertMinutesToHours(result, days, hours, minutes) to be transformed into convertMinutesToHours(result, "jours", "heures", "minutes") when translate(french) is applied instead of the 3 last parameters but obviously i'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function `translate()` always returns `undefined` result.

You can make it return an array with `return` keyword.
You can then "spread" resulting array across `convertMinutesToHours()` arguments using [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
convertMinutesToHours(flatResult, ...translate(french))
```

Comment: Thanks! works like magic! My Switch was badly defined as it was the last solution I tried and i wrote it too quickly.